# Find an orthonormal base of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a scalar product 
$$\langle 
\begin{bmatrix}
       x \\
       y
     \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
       a \\
       b
     \end{bmatrix}\rangle = 2xa + xb + ya + yb$$

So I have to find an orthonormal base with this scalar product. I do not know how to even start.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

First put $ \begin{bmatrix}
       a \\
       b
     \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
       1 \\
       1
     \end{bmatrix}$.

Then $\langle 
\begin{bmatrix}
       x \\
       y
     \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
       a \\
       b
     \end{bmatrix}\rangle=0 \iff 3x+2y=0$.

Now find $\begin{bmatrix}
       x \\
       y
     \end{bmatrix}$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}
       x \\
       y
     \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
       1 \\
       1
     \end{bmatrix}$ are linearily independent and $3x+2y=0.$

Then $\begin{bmatrix}
       x \\
       y
     \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
       1 \\
       1
     \end{bmatrix}$ are orthogonal and $\{\begin{bmatrix}
       x \\
       y
     \end{bmatrix}$ , $\begin{bmatrix}
       1 \\
       1
     \end{bmatrix}\}$ are is a basis.

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

For your specific two dimensional case it is pretty easy to find a solution as @fred pointed out in his answer.

The general strategy is to find a basis of your vector space: $\left\{ \mathbf{v_1, ...,v_n}\right\}$

Then you apply the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to your basis.

For example in this case start with $\left\{(1, 1),\space (1, 0)\right\}$

$<(1, 0),\space (1, 1)> = 2 + 0 + 1 + 0 = 3$

$\mathbf{u_1} = \mathbf{v_1} = (1, 0)$

$\mathbf{u_2} = \mathbf{v_2} - \text{proj}_{\mathbf{u_1}}(\mathbf{u_2})
 = \mathbf{v_2} - \frac{<\mathbf{u_1}, \mathbf{u_2}>}{||\mathbf{u_1}||^2}\mathbf{u_1} = (1,1) -(\frac{3}{2},0)=(-\frac{1}{2},1)$

We can check that the base is indeed orthogonal:
$<(1, 0),(-\frac{1}{2},1)> = -2\frac{1}{2} + 1 + 0 + 0 = 0$

To find an orthonormal basis simply divide the vectors by their magnitude:$||u_1|| = \sqrt{2}$, $||u_2|| = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} -1 + 1}$.